# Can I have a field in the message portion of a notification email that only displays if filled? (NOT standard "Include Entry Details")?

Tags: cognito-forms

We have our email notifications on Cognito Forms pushing via notification email into various other platforms (inbound email to create tickets) so the standard Cognito Forms email notification does not lend itself well to display.

I want to create a more "plain-text" style email using the message field (screenshot below) but I only want the heading and field to display ***if the field is filled in*** as we have conditional logic branches so, as a certainty, some fields present on the form won't ever be filled in.

[image]

Is this possible?